# Get calling class name from abstract class in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I recently started learning C#, I'm programming in various languages like PHP, JavaScript, Go, Rust, Elixir, a bit of Java and Python.

I always was fascinated by C# and I decided now to give it a go.

So far so good, my process of learning a new language is by trying to replicate a variety of things from other languages, especially from PHP where I'm most strong.

**TLTR:**
How I could implement this in C#?

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

abstract class Foo
{
    public static function className(): string
    {
        return static::class;
    }
}

final class Bar extends Foo
{
}

echo Bar::className() . PHP_EOL;
```

The code above returns "Bar" instead of "Foo" because we are calling the name of the static, where static is the class that we are calling the className method from.

In C# I managed to do that:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace LearningConsole
{
    abstract class Foo
    {
        public static string ClassName()
        {
            return MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
        }
    }

    class Bar : Foo
    {

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Bar.ClassName());
        }
    }
}
```

But this returns the "Foo" class name instead of "Bar", is there a way to get the name of the class that invoking the ClassName method?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**
The reason I'm using a static method is that I'm trying to accomplish something similar in C# like this in PHP:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

interface Dummy {}

abstract class Base implements Dummy
{
    public static function create(...$args): Dummy
    {
        $callingClass = static::class;
        return new $callingClass(...$args);
    }
}

final class Bar extends Base
{
    protected function __construct() {}
}

final class Foo extends Base
{
    protected function __construct() {}
}

$foo = Foo::create();
$bar = Bar::create();
echo get_class($foo) . PHP_EOL.
     get_class($bar) . PHP_EOL;
```

The above will output:
Foo
Bar

Maybe in C# that kind of "magic" is considered bad practice, but it could be handy for various occasions.

Thanks!

**EDIT 2:**
That C# is not working (obviously), but it is my understanding of what could be a good compromise for achieving somehow the above example:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace LearningConsole
{
    interface Dummy
    {
    }

    abstract class Base : Dummy
    {
        public static Dummy Create(Dummy obj, params dynamic[] args)
        {
            var constructor = typeof(obj).GetConstructor();
            constructor.invoke(null, args);
        }
    }

    class Foo : Base
    {
    }

    class Bar : Base
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var foo = Base.Create(Foo, null);
            var bar = Base.Create(Bar, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does it need to be a static method?

Comment: The static ClassName is Foo.ClassName, and can never be Bar.ClassName. Even Intellisense in Visual studio says it's Foo.ClassName. This is because static mehods  don't require an instance of the class, and really for statics they just form a part of the name, just like a namespace. To do what you want, you have to implement static ClassName in each class in the hierarchy, but add the new keyword to stop the compiler from complaining, i.e. "public static new string ClassName()"

Comment: You should use `typeof(Bar).Name` instead if you don't hold an instance of that type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve what you are looking for with a little help from generics.  Here is an example

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = Base.Create<Foo>();
        var bar = Base.Create<Bar>();
        Console.WriteLine(foo.GetType().Name);
        Console.WriteLine(bar.GetType().Name);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public abstract class Base
{
    public static T Create<T>(params object[] args) where T : Base
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);
    }
}

public class Bar : Base
{

}

public class Foo : Base
{

}
```

Comment: That looks cool! (I wish since a long time ago that PHP had generics...) That is basically what I tried to do with Edit 2 of my post, I will try it now! Thanks!

Comment: I updated my example to add support for passing arguments to the constructor

Comment: wow thanks! I was just about to ask you! Could you explain me (or just give me a link so I can read), previously you had "return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();" Which is ok, I can read that, but this: "return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);" is kind of magic, I mean the (T) stuff, so you remove the generic <T> after the CreateInstance and  you add (T) tuple before Activator

Comment: The (T) before is a type cast.  If you call Activator.CreateInstance(type, args) it returns an object. The (T) casts the object to a type of T. e.g. whatever is passed into the generic as the type.

Comment: ah lol, I didn't think about it, it is the same way like PHP typecasting (and other languages as well, I thought it has something to do with tuples but it was simpler than that! Thank you! Until a few minutes ago I thought that this wasn't possible in C#, having a base class is a good compromise! Now if I may ask another question, is it possible to make Create method of Base abstract class not inheritable so Foo and Bar will not be able to use Create method?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to restrict inheritance of static members in C#. That being said, calling Base.Create<Foo>() will give you the same thing as calling Foo.Create<Foo>().  Tools will usually let you know it can be simplified to calling Base

Comment: But isn't it possible to check the calling method, and in the case is not Base class to throw an exception?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199583/discussion-between-bhmahler-and-panosru).

Answer (score 4):

Thi code does not translate well to C#. You might want to consume it like this

```
  Console.WriteLine(typeof(Bar).Name);
```

Having classname as a property is perfectly fine for a non static method/property. If you need the type of a static class you can always go with the example I gave or have that property be non static and in a instanced object

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bar b = new Bar();
            Console.WriteLine(b.ClassName());

        }
    }

    abstract class Foo
    {
        public string ClassName()
        {
            return GetType().Name;
        }
    }

    class Bar : Foo
    {

    }
```

In the end, even if there's a way to do what you want, you should ask why and I personally think you should do it the C# way. also remembert Type is an object in C# with lots of cools things in it.

if you have an instance you can do

```
instance.GetType()
```

if you just have a type you can do

```
typeof(Bar)
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply! I have updated my original question to illustrate better what I want to accomplish, but from what I read online I don't think that there is a possible way to do that kind of "magic" in C# even though that C#'s OOP is much more superior than PHP's OOP. I'm working on an alternative way to get a similar effect in C# I will post it in Edit 2 if I manage to make it work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

In this way you will print: Foo Bar

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        var bar = new Bar();
        Console.Write(foo.ClassName());
        Console.Write(bar.ClassName());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public string ClassName()
    {
        return GetType().Name;
    }
}

class Bar : Foo
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is Static methods do not work on the instance of the class, they are directly associated with the class itself in your case it id Foo. Here you can access the ClassName method from derived class Bar, but it associated with Foo.

So if you write a static method in the class and compile it, and when you try to view the IL, it will be same as any other class accessing the static member.